# How can I fix WinRAR Error?

Tags: rar

I have an evaluation copy of Win RAR in my Windows 2003 server.
Today I tried to unzip a file which is around 7 GB in size, after completing the unzip I am getting an error "The file currept". I am doing the same for the last couple of weeks.

What will be root cause of this problem.

Please advice

Comment: You're asking this in the wrong site.  Ask in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As @rrirower already indicated: this site is about recommending software for specific requirements – not for solving issues with software you already have. I further agree that [SU] sounds like a good place for your issue. Hint: Each SE site has a specific `/help/on-topic` page, which I recommend reading before posting your first question on it, and a `/tour` page which is also worth visiting. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe my app helps: https://github.com/KYHSGeekCode/Unzip-Corrupt

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading and using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) instead.  It can handle multiple different compression types, and might yield different results.

It could also be that the file is corrupt and therefore can't be opened properly, in which case you've got bigger problems.

Also, please be aware that support and updates for [Windows Server 2003 ends on July 14th](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/)